# Can you download a Qualtrics data file to blob storage using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: rest, api, azure-data-factory, qualtrics

Qualtrics provides an API that allows you to download your survey data as a file.  The API call looks like this:

```
https://[tenant].qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/[Survey_ID]/export-responses/[File_ID]/file
```

The response contains ALL the data (in .csv format) and must be written straight to a file (i.e. responses.csv)in blob storage for further processing.

I've tried using a web activity and a copy activity (w/ Rest) with no luck.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is what a sample result response from the API call looks like:

```
RecordedDate,RecipientFirstName,RecipientLastName,CSULBID,Score
2020-02-07 23:21:50,Darth,Vader,00001234,56
2020-02-07 23:21:50,Darth,Maul,00005678,56
```

Comment: I am unable to get the API URL for the survey.  I tried using this https://{datacenterid}.qualtrics.com/API/V3/{API Token} but got 404-Not-found. I tried using this under GET https://sjc1.qualtrics.com/API/V3/whoami and {token number} in bearer token in postman but got 404-Not-found. Can you direct me how to get the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into Azure Logic Apps?

It has a very intuitive way to call web API and create CSV out of it.  It's explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations

My group tried to use Azure Data Factory, but it seemed like Azure Logic App did a better job, and ended up creating the API calling and CSV making step as a Logic App.

Comment: Thank you - that was relatively painless.